# Fonts Awesome: como alterar a fonte em a:hover via CSS?

Tags: html5, css3, font-awesome

Como alterar a fonte de "Regular Icons" para "Solid Icons" via CSS. No https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet as duas possuem o mesmo código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
a#edit{
    color: #f00;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: none;
}
a#edit:link::before{
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content:"\f1c6 ";
   }
a#edit:hover{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph. 
</p><p> <a id="edit" href="#"> </a>
</p><p> <a href="#">.</a>
</p><p> <i class="fas fa-file-archive"> f1c6 </i>
</p><p> <i class="far fa-file-archive"> f1c6 </i>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Então, no caso seria ideal você trabalhar com a fonte direto, sem a utilização das classes do font-awesome, você pode utilizar o a popriedade content no css, e especificar a fonte como a font-awesome. Lá na visualização do detalhe do ícone que você selecionou, tem um código do ícone específico, a documentação da versão 5 está ótima, vale a pena dar uma olhada!

Comment: O que voce indica, já fiz, e está no codigo da pergunta. Os dois códigos são iguais. como altero a apresentação?
Preciso de ajuda nivel Hard. :D

Comment: Coloquei as duas representações para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Cara com ::before é impossível pelo que eu andei lendo... Quando vc tenta trocar o de `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Regular";` para `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";` ele não carrega a fonte fica só um quadrado... Se vc reparar no Dev Tools o ícone já é um `::before` e não tem como ter um `::before::before` A solução seria usando o `<i>` Se mesmo se quiser eu te respondo com mais detalhes no campo de **Resposta**

Comment: Olá @hugocsl se possível gostaria da resposta sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma alternativa sem usar `::before` pois o novo padrão da https://fontawesome.com/ já coloca o ícone como um `::before` e não tem como vc fazer um `::before::before`

Aqui está a documentação oficial sobre o uso do `::before` no novo padão: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements

Agora vamos ao que interessa, Para fazer o que vc quer basta seguir a estrutura do HTML e colocar no `<i>` a classe ***branco*** ou ***preto*** para mostrar e esconder os ícones no `:hover` dando o efeito que acredito que vc quer.

Veja no Snippet abaixo que vc vai entender melhor.

```css
.icone {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.branco{
    position: relative;
    color: red;
}
.preto {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: transparent;
}
.icone:hover .preto {
    color: black;
}
.icone:hover .branco {
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<span class="icone">
    <i class="far fa-file-archive branco"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-file-archive preto" ></i> 
    f1c6 
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="icone">
    <i class="far fa-address-book branco"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-address-book preto" ></i> 
    f2b9 
</span>
```